# Using two asymmetric uplinks

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, opnsense

My current network topology is:

[image: Network topology]

Fact Firewall (I tested with OPNsense and IPFire, but I'm open to further suggestions)
and the whole "ORANGE/DMZ" stuff are actually VMs/containers in a physical LXD server
should not impact (but I might be wrong, of course).

My current setup (using IPFire ATM) is fully functional, **BUT** it uses only `ISP_B`
for communication.

I can easily switch to use `ISP_A` and it works fine just the same (with floating IP
limitation, of course).

My attempts to use both failed.

Target would be:

1. Use `ISP_A` for all outgoing traffic originated from `GREEN/LAN` and `ORANGE/DMZ`.
2. Redirect all web traffic (ports 80, 81 and 443) to `webserver` on `ORANGE/DMZ`
   **and allow proper reply**
3. Redirect a few other ports (non-standard, but essentially sporting `ssh`/`git`
   protocol) to `userver` on `ORANGE/DMZ` **allowing proper response**
4. If at all possible I would also like to be able to use `ISP_B` for all traffic
   in case of `ISP_A` failure, but I suspect this is matter for another question.

My attempts failed miserably essentially because if I set the `default gateway` to
`ISP_A` packets coming from `ISP_B` get NATted, then correctly sent to `Firewall` and redirected to `webserver` (so far, so good), but replies are sent from `Firewall` to `ISP_A` which did never see the original packet, so it can't divine where to send it
and simply drops it.

I am missing something, but I couldn't understand what.

> Note 1: both modem/routers are set in "DMZ mode" (i.e.: full port redirect) to Firewall (`192.168.1.9`).

> Note 2: Analysis above was done under `IPFire`, but `OPNsense` behavior is similar.

> Note 3: I would like to understand what should be done in such circumstances, not just "how to fix", if possible.

I am ready to provide any required info, including full configs, if deemed useful.

### UPDATE:

Here follows the log of everything I did from OPNsense installation to date.

The last part (Port redirection) does not seem to work properly, even if rule is triggered and logs (see below).

##### OPNsense setup log

- login as root on console
- setup devices for all three networks:

  - WAN:

    - second device (vtnet1)
    - Fixed IP (192.168.1.9/24)
    - Default gateway (192.168.1.1)
    - No DHCP server
  - LAN:

    - first device (vtnet0)
    - Fixed IP (192.168.7.9/24)
    - No default gateway
    - No DHCP server (we will enable it later)
  - OPT1:

    - third device (vtnet2)
    - Fixed IP (192.168.9.9/24)
    - No default gateway
    - No DHCP server
- Access to the Internet from LAN should work as expected (e.g.: from `cinderella`).
- Access to the Internet from OPT1
  (e.g.: from`webserver`) **does not** work;
  DNS resolution **does not** work either.
- Open OPNsense management page (`https://192.168.7.9`)
- Login as root/opnsense
- Follow setup wizard and change `root` password.
- There should be no change in functionality.
- Enable OPT1/DMZ access to the Internet:

  - Interfaces -> [OPT1]

    - check "Prevent interface removal"
    - "Description" -> DMZ
    - "IPv6 Configuration Type" -> None
    - `[Save]` and `[Apply changes]`
  - Firewall -> Rules -> DMZ:

    - Add new rule `[+]`
    - "Source" -> `DMZ net`
    - "Category" -> `dmz`
    - "Description" -> `Allow DMZ to access Internet`
    - `[Save]` and `[Apply changes]`
- Access to the Internet from OPT1/DMZ
  (e.g.: from`webserver`) **works**;
  DNS resolution **does also work**.
- All hosts (LAN+DMZ) should use default gateway
  (192.168.1.1) to reach out.
- Save config to `config-OPNsense.condarelli.it-01.xml`
- Add second gateway:

  - System -> Gateways -> Single

    - WAN_GW(active) -> Edit

      - "Priority" -> `10`
      - `[Save]`
    - Add new gateway `[+]`

      - "Name" -> `Backup`
      - "Description" -> `DSL backup connection (with fixed IP)`
      - "Interface" -> `WAN`
      - "IP address" -> `192.168.1.2`
      - "Priority" -> `100`
      - `[Save]`
    - `[Apply changes]`
- No change in functionality
- Save config to `config-OPNsense.condarelli.it-02.xml`
- Force DMZ to use `Backup` as gateway:

  - Firewall -> Rules -> DMZ

    - Allow DMZ to access Internet -> Edit

      - "Gateway" -> `Backup - 192.168.1.2`
      - `[Save]`
    - Add new rule `[+]`

      - "Protocol" -> `TCP/UDP`
      - "Source" -> `DMZ net`
      - "Destination" -> `DMZ address`
      - "Destination port range" -> from `DNS` to `DNS`
      - "Category" -> `dmz`
      - "Description" -> `Allow access to DNS server`
      - `[Save]`
    - `[Apply changes]`
- Functionality should remain the same, but hosts on
  DMZ should use `Backup` (192.168.1.2) as gateway.
  This cam be checked using `traceroute`
- Save config to `config-OPNsense.condarelli.it-03.xml`
- Create port forward from Internet to`webserver` via `Backup` gateway:

  - Firewall -> Categories

    - Add new category `[+]`

      - "Name" -> `web`
      - "Color" -> `ff14ff`
      - `[Save]`
- Firewall -> Aliases

  - Add new alias `[+]`

    - "Name" -> `WEBports`
    - "Type" -> `Port(s)`
    - "Categories" -> `web`
    - "Content" -> `80 81 443`
    - "Description" -> `Web standard ports`
    - `[Save]`
  - Add new alias `[+]`

    - "Name" -> `webserver`
    - "Type" -> `Host(s)`
    - "Categories" -> `dmz web`
    - "Content" -> `192.168.9.8`
    - "Description" -> `Nginx web server and reverse proxy`
    - `[Save]`
- Firewall -> NAT -> Port Forward

  - Add new rule `[+]`
  - "Destination" -> `WAN address`
  - "Destination port range " -> `WEBports`
  - "Redirect target IP" -> `webserver`
  - "Category" -> `web dmz`
  - "Description" -> `Allow external access to Nginx Proxy Manager`

    - `[Save]`
  - `[Apply changes]`

If I try to access my `nginx` server using a DNS entry pointing to `ISP_B` external address I can see in logs:

[image: redirect log]

> Note: `79.34.242.11` is the (floating) IP currently assigned to `ISP_A` modem.

### UPDATE2:

Sorry if it was not clear but I have two `DMZ` rules:

[image: DMZ rules]

The first allows access to DNS server on firewall and the second redirects everything else to ISP_B.

I am unsure why the first is needed, but without it DNS resolution does not work for hosts sitting on DMZ.

Hosts connected to DMZ really use ISP_B/Backup/192.168.1.2 to reach the internet; that bit works. What does **not** work is getting back the answer after the request packet was (apparently correctly) redirected to DMZ/webserver.

The port forwarding rule looks like:

[image]

and apparently works as logs above seem to indicate.

I am unable to understand why response packets seem to get lost (and how can I trace them to understand what went south).

Unfortunately I'm very far from being a net (and OPNsense) guru.

Specific instructions on how to overcome the problem (or further diagnose it) would be *very* welcome.

Comment: You only redirect DNS to a different gateway. If you want all traffic from DMZ to hit `192.168.1.2` you should set protocol to any, and leave source and destination port blank.

Comment: @vidarlo: I added further details. Second gateway usage seems working, tested using `traceroute` from `webserver` on DMZ. I can't understand how to redirect answers to forwarded requests. Please feel free to ask details you may need.

Comment: You have to define rules that redirects those answers to the gateway of your choice. Yes, it can quickly become complex. Especially when you mate it with NAT.

Comment: @vidarlo: can, in theory, understand the need, but I haven't the first idea about how to go to implement such a beast. If You could be so kind to provide an example or point me to relevant documentation... Note I don't need overcomplex stuff, "just" redirect port 80/443 to a single host (webserver) and get back results. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically policy based routing.

In OpnSense (and pfsense) you do this in a firewall rule:
[image: Firewall]

Here the gateway will be used for packets matching that rule. You can add additional gateways in addition to default under System - Gateways.

You will have to define firewall rules for the different traffic types, and assign them to correct gateways. The firewall rules can match on all the usual stuff - source IP, source network and so forth to send traffic according to your wishes.

Comment: I added an update to detail what I tried to do without success. I need a bit more detail to sort this out. Sorry being so dumb :(